# Position label on curved edges in ggnetwork

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

I am using the r package ggnetwork to plot a weighted directed graph.

My goal is to plot a label indicating the weight of each edge.
Since the network is directed, I use the field curvature in the function `geom_edges()` to avoid overlapping edges. Then, I use the function `geom_edgetext()` to plot the weight of each edge.

My problem is that I do not know how to provide the new coordinates of the edges (after the curvature has been set) to `geom_edgetext()`.

As a result, labels are positioned as if edges weren't curved.
Any idea?

Following a reproducible example showing where I got so far:

```
# Load libraries
library(igraph)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnetwork)

# Create adjacency matrix
m <- matrix(c(c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0),
               c(1,0,1,1,0,0,0),
               c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0),
               c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0),
               c(1,0,0,0,0,1,1),
               c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1),
               c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0)), nrow = 7, ncol = 7, byrow=T)

# Assign weights: column-normalize m
D <- diag(1/c(apply(m,2,sum)))
m <- m%*%D

# Create igraph object
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjmatrix = m, mode = "directed", weighted = TRUE)

# Create ggnetwork object
n <- ggnetwork(g, layout = "fruchtermanreingold", cell.jitter = 0.25)

# Plot graph with weights
ggplot(n, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
geom_edges(size = 0.3, color = "grey50", arrow = arrow(length = unit(6,"pt")), curvature = 0.2) +
geom_nodes(size = 8, color = "orange") +
geom_edgetext(aes(label =  round(weight,2)), color = "grey25")+
theme_blank()+ theme(legend.position="none")
```